# Escaping ' in a query-string - is it even possible?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a large php application (purely php, no frameworks, etc.) which uses an oracle-db.
All queries are executed like this:

```
oci_parse($conn_id,"insert into table (bla) values ('bla')");
oci_execute($stmt)
```

I know this is bad! No need pointing out stuff like "use bind" or something similar. I know that, but I can't change this.

What we all also know is that you have to escape characters. 
This question is especially about the `'` charcter.

I have many queries like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2,field3,field4) VALUES ('bla,bla','blub', 'mimi'm', 'mu's'c'hle')";
$query2 = "UPDATE table SET field1 =  'bla,bla', field2 = 'blub', field3 = 'mimi'm', field4 = 'mu's'c'hle' WHERE field5 = 'lol'zj'd'"
```

Sure, normally they do not have so many `'` in it - but thats just for demonstration.

Now to the question: 
Is there any way to validate/escape the whole query-string in php? I can't think/find of a way to accomplish this, no matter how I think of it.

It's obvious that it's easy to escape all values before building the query-strings, by just replacing `'` with `''` - but is it possible when you only have the whole query as a string (like the examples above)? I personally can't think of an "universal solution"...

Comment: So you don't want to use PDO but want the benefits?  Won't even consider, [oci_bind_by_name()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

Comment: I dream of using this - I have not written this application (I would probably commit suicide if Id have)... and its not like "oh ok I change it to PDO, just 10 hours work"....

Comment: Naw, I hear you.  My sympathies.

Comment: If all you get is whole query strings, I would create a simple query-parser to handle this situation. I would recommend finding another way to andle your strings though

Comment: Doing this after the query string is already constructed is, quite frankly, ridiculous. This is something you should be doing on each input value as the query is being constructed.

Comment: @BjørneMalmanger I don't believe a standard query parser would work, see my answer below.  Unless there is some type of parser I am unaware of which can handle this, it has been a while since I have had to use parser theory :-)

Comment: "I know this is bad!" ... "but I can't change it".  Why not?  Should be a priority I think

Comment: I don't know about you guys, but I guess some of you know this kind of situation... it's not always easy to persuade the boss that his whole software sucks, especially if he's stubborn and an oldschool-developer and also old in age and knows everything better and time pressure and this and that and totally believes in it and and and and... ;) You know theres always this point in software, when you can't make it "good" anymore by trying to fix things... the only way you could fix this whole application is by completely starting over...

Comment: I believe you (and feel sorry for your situation), but I see this reasoning used too often.  After a while this software that you are trying to patch together with a bunch of hacks (no offense) will have YOUR name attached to it, and eventually someone else's headache.  You need to push back harder for what you know is right (imho).

Comment: @tenhouse Don't touch those punchcards, you'll get them out of order and the program will never work again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is insoluble with traditional means, at the time when the query is already built:

1. Trying to simply add a slash to every apostrophe, of course will not work, because you are escaping the delimiter apostrophes as well as the "in-value" apostrophes.
2. There is no function or regular expression to determine which are the in-value apostrophes and which are the value-delimiting apostrophes.
3. Even a parser won't help you because part of a parser's job is to tell you when the query has invalid syntax, but not to fix that syntax; as soon as it hits an apostrophe out of place and the following character is not a comma, it will baulk.

Let's take part of your second example:

```
field3 = 'mimi'm', field4 = 'mu's'c'hle'
```

A normal query parser would see the `field3` value as `'mini'` followed by an erroneous `m`, where it expects a comma.  This is not something a parser is designed to handle.

So suppose we write something custom to handle this.  Let's say we decide that the apostrophe, given that it isn't followed by a comma, must be part of the value.  That's fine, but what about the next apostrophe, which is intended to be a delimiter?

How does our code know whether the apostrophe is a delimiter, as opposed to the value actually containing an apostrophe followed by a comma?  In fact, the value could contain something that looks exactly like the rest of the query!  (Furthermore, how would we detect queries that actually *are* invalid, once we start to question the structure of the query itself in this way).

**tl;dr**

GIGO = garbage in, garbage out

You can't write (traditional) software to sort out an arbitrary mess!

Comment: Perhaps AI could be an option? ;-P

Comment: and this is all I wanted. Just the confirmation that it won't work. I had kinda similar thoughts..... also funny that it looks like you were the only person able to read and not just write something.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is DEFINETELY not failproof, or even elegant, but it does work on the given querys, as a "proof of concept" so to speak...

do not use the function in a production server.. it WILL break sooner (not later ;))

```
<?php


$query = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2,field3,field4) VALUES ('bla,bla','blub','mimi'm','mu's'c'hle')";
$query2 = "UPDATE table SET field1 =  'bla,bla', field2 = 'blub', field3 = 'mimi'm', field4 = 'mu's'c'hle' WHERE field5 = 'lol'zj'd'";

function clean_given_query($qry)
{
    if(strpos($qry , " VALUES "))
    {   
        //the easy way, since we know exactly how many fields we have here
        $qra = explode('VALUES', $qry);
        if(count($qra) == 2)
        {
            // qra[0] = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2,field3,field4)"
            // qra[1] = "('bla,bla','blub', 'mimi'm', 'mu's'c'hle')";
            $qtemp = explode('(', $qra[0]);
            $qtemp = $qtemp[1]; // we can loose the insert -part for now
            $fieldcount = count(explode(',',$qtemp)); // now we know how many fields we want to populate
            $qra[1] = explode("','", $qra[1]); // dirty values....
            if(count($qra[1]) === $fieldcount) //make sure we have the correkt value count
            {
                $values = array();
                foreach($qra[1] as $i => $val)
                {
                    if($i==0)
                        $val = substr($val, 3); // we know $val is a string and index 0 starts with (' which we need to remove!
                    if($i == count($qra[1])-1) // last item  needs to be cropped at the end
                        $val = substr($val, 0, count($val)-3); //also a string as we know.

                    $val = addslashes($val); //escape the string according to your needs
                    $values[] = $val;
                }
                return $qra[0]." VALUES ('".implode("','", $values)."')";
            }

        }
    }
    else if (strpos($qry, "SET"))
    {
        $qra = explode('=', $qry);
        // $qra[0] = "UPDATE table SET field1";
        // $qra[1] = "'bla,bla', field2";
        $save = $qra[0]."='";

        foreach($qra as $i => $mixed)
        {   
            if($i == 0) // qra[0]  holds nothing to edit!
                continue;

            $parts = explode(',', $mixed); // [0] 'bla    [1] bla'  [2] field2
            $nextfield = array_pop($parts);

            $val = implode(',', $parts); // $val = 'bla,bla'
            if(strpos($nextfield , "WHERE"))
            {
                list($val, $nextfield) = explode("WHERE",$nextfield);
                $nextfield = " WHERE ".$nextfield;
            }
            $val = trim($val);
            $val = substr($val, 1, count($val)-2); //$val  bla,bla
            $val = addslashes($val); // escape according to your needs

            if($val!=="" and strpos($nextfield , "WHERE") === false)
                $save .= $val."', ".$nextfield."='";
            elseif($val!=="" and strpos($nextfield , "WHERE"))
                $save .= $val."' ".$nextfield."='";
            else
            {
                $val = trim($nextfield);
                $val = substr($val, 1, count($val)-2); //$val  bla,bla
                $val = addslashes($val); // escape according to your needs
                $save .= $val."'";
            }
        }
        return $save;
    }
}

echo $query.PHP_EOL;
echo clean_given_query($query).PHP_EOL;

echo $query2.PHP_EOL;
echo clean_given_query($query2).PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2,field3,field4) VALUES ('bla,bla','blub','mimi'm','mu's'c'hle')
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2,field3,field4)  VALUES ('bla,bla','blub','mimi\'m','mu\'s\'c\'hle')
UPDATE table SET field1 =  'bla,bla', field2 = 'blub', field3 = 'mimi'm', field4 = 'mu's'c'hle' WHERE field5 = 'lol'zj'd'
UPDATE table SET field1 ='bla,bla',  field2 ='blub',  field3 ='mimi\'m',  field4 ='mu\'s\'c\'hle'  WHERE  field5 ='lol\'zj\'d'
```

With a little bit of effort, and correct reg_exp instead of simple explode/implodes and the proper escape function for your needs you can build a function that is capable of cleaning given querys

Comment: haha dude this is pretty impressive, especially because it looks like you had some work done writing that...I appreciate this and now I'm not quite sure which to mark the correct answer since your solution does work... :D

Comment: @tenhouse, thank you.. yes, because my short first (and especially 'not correct question answered') answer got downvoted I thought - just as mom told me - to try again... and better this time;)

Comment: Yeah this is very interesting.  I think it might work on a very small subset of the problem.  There are issues though, as pointed out by @itsid.  For example I think it won't work if there is a space after a comma, like `'value', 'value'` (see line marked "dirty values", there is no space there).  I'd also like to know how it handles a case which includes values like this (this is intended to result in a single value, the apostrophes and comma in the middle are "in-value", part of the input to the query): `'this is','actually one single value'`.

Comment: the code above yes, very very small subset, it took me ~15mins to write the code above so I'd bet you'll find a code breaking query within seconds.. in general, I don't know, I think it could be done. A large set of regex patterns (vor legal inserts, updates etc.) and a smart enough switch case scenario. But it'll be quite a task to do so. A much easier task is to simply rewrite the necessary parts of the script to escape all the values before they're in a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just do a simple `str_replace()`. I.E. `str_replace("'", "\'", $string);` .

EDIT:
You can also do

```
$str = "INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) 
                        VALUES (
                                replace(" . $value . ", Chr(39), Chr(39) & Chr(39)), 
                                replace(" . $value . ", Chr(39), Chr(39) & Chr(39))
                               );";
```

As Chr(39) refers to '.

Comment: That would replace all `'`, but he only want to escape the 's inside the '<somestring>'

Comment: Why the downvotes? He's right. Alternative: `preg_replace("/'/", "\'", $query_arg);`

Comment: @BjørneMalmanger it's a bit ridiculous to build an entire query string like he's given in the example and then *go back* and escape the data. This is something that should be done when the query is *constructed*, not immediately before it is run.

Comment: @Sammitch that doesn't change the fact that this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Sammitch of course it is, but his problem didn't describe how he came into this mess. He only asked for a solution for it ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table(field) Values('".addslashes("'")."')";
```

I think that's failsave or, even better

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO table(field) Values('%s')", addslashes("'"));
```

because that's most liekely easier to read in case you want to extend the insert someday.

[edit]
as far as I know it doesn't matter which flavor of sql you use if you only want to have the strings escaped, but just in case addslashes works just as well here.
And yes... there are some specialised sql-escape functions in php,

And.. rereading the question.. just having the query-string, not having the initial values it's rather hard to properly escape everything.

Comment: Is that at all right?  Wanna say Oracle is more like Postgres when it comes to quote escaping... If anything maybe [pg_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php)?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your problem it should work

```
$name = addslashes("mu's'c'hle");
$query = "INSERT INTO teste (teste) VALUES ('$name')";
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem.

Comment: Why u give downvote? What is wrong with my Answers? BBe constructive, or I'll give you a downvote to

Comment: Your answer does not address the question.  The queries are already constructed, the value `"mu's'c'hle"` is not known as a discrete value -- it is all jumbled up in the query already.  Furthermore threatening to use downvotes inappropriately for personal retribution is incredibly poor form.  Especially when you don't actually even have the reputation to have earned that privilege yet.

Comment: If you not explain why downvote, And just say, "I do not think you understand the problem." I can understand that you are using downvotes inappropriately and acting authoritatively.

Comment: Well actually, I did not "just say" that, in fact I did explain in my previous comment quite clearly why your answer was wrong.  But just in case, let me repeat in different words: **The input to the problem is the whole query, not just the individual value "mu's'c'hle"**.  Therefore you have not addressed the problem as stated.  That is why you got a downvote.  Or, if you won't take my word for it, why don't you read the OP's comment on my answer, where he agrees that I understood the problem and other users did not?

Comment: sorry but the downvotes are absolutely legitime here. you didn't ever bother reading the question I guess - quote from the question "It's obvious that it's easy to escape all values before building the query-strings, by just replacing `'` with `''` - [...]" - what I already wrote in the question is exactly what you answer.

Comment: In my opinion anyone who sincerely try to answer any question deserves a negative vote. Because it discourages the User. Only spammers, cheaters ... they deserve negative votes.

Comment: @itsid proposed a good answer and not gave downvote to others

Answer (score -1):

Unless you want to write something that can interpret the query and determine where the error is at and then somehow determine what the proper fix is, there is no way.

Further, if you do this you still haven't fixed your bigger issue, which is sql injection.

Comment: Just to be clear, the proper way to do this IS to clean the data before you put it in the string.

Comment: The down vote is uncalled for.

He specifically states:
It's obvious that it's easy to escape all values before building the query-strings, by just replacing ' with '' - but is it possible when you only have the whole query as a string (like the examples above)? I personally can't think of an "universal solution"...